# Powershell Script to run Unit Test using MSTest.exe

Tags: unit-testing, powershell, mstest

How to run all the unit test in a solution directory using Powershell Script.
I tried with the below command

```
$tool = '"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\MSTest.exe"'

$x = ""; dir D:\DropBuildOutput\*.Tests.dll -Recurse | foreach { $x += "/testcontainer:""$_"" " }; iex "$tool $x"
```

But its failing with error below.How can i run all the tests and generate results?

```
iex : At line:1 char:79
+ ...  (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\MSTest.exe" /testcont ...
+                                                                  ~
You must provide a value expression following the '/' operator.
At line:1 char:79
+ ... STest.exe" /testcontainer:"D:\DropBuildOutput\_PublishedWebsites\SCJ. ...
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Unexpected token 
'testcontainer:"D:\DropBuildOutput\_PublishedWebsites\aaa.aaa.aaa.aaa\bin\xxx.aaa.aaa.Tests.dll"' in 
expression or statement.
At line:2 char:100
+ ... -Recurse | foreach { $x += "/testcontainer:""$_"" " }; iex "$tool $x"
+                                                            ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [Invoke-Expression], ParseException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ExpectedValueExpression,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeExpressionCommand
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the call operator `&` instead of `Invoke-Expression`:

```
& $Tool $x
```

Comment: still getting error  At line:4 char:102
+ ... l -Recurse | foreach { $x += "/testcontainer:""$_"" " }; & "$tool $x"
+                                                                ~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: ("C:\Program Fil...rms.Tests.dll" :String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException